# Java Webpage - open editable excel and save it

Tags: java, excel, azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, office365

We have an existing usecase where external user downloads an excel worksheet from our java based webpage -> edits offline on his/her machine -> uploads back on our webpage to process it. Spreadsheet uses built in functions and conditional formatting. We have around 12K users.

With newer versions and apis from microsoft, i have seen websites (like box.com) opening editable excel right in browser -> lets user make edits -> save it right there.

I tried to find on microsoft docs and google but couldn't find any pointers except personal one-drive file that can be opened on browser. Found MS graph but that didn't help either.

Can someone please guide me or point to some documentation to achieve this. My company has active office 365 business account for employees and internal use.

thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on more research (read google) and analyzing netwrork calls for box.com website, found that Microsoft has an api  called WOPI to do this

https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You will need to register yourself as cloud provider. More at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/integration/integrate-with-office

So you own and keep your files with you but use MS apps as pure software as service.

Comment: Hi @Jags, Thanks for your sharing, you could accept your answer. In this case, others could directly find the useful solution.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT stackoverflow does not allow accepting my own answer for 2 days based on my reputation :)